# Visualize depsgraph?

Tags: python, blend-files, depsgraph

Is there a convenient way to visualize the dependency graph of a Blender file?

If so, does it provide granularity showing where and how the dependency occurs?

If you create a dependency cycle, then the resulting error message will say something like:

```
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBCube/Transform Component/TRANSFORM_CONSTRAINTS() depends on
  OBCube.001/Transform Component/TRANSFORM_FINAL() via 'Copy Location'
  OBCube.001/Transform Component/TRANSFORM_CONSTRAINTS() via 'ObConstraints -> Done'
```

So clearly this information is kept track of internally.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()` will return a [`Depsgraph()` Python object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html).

**`bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().debug_relations_graphviz("/SomePath/SomeFile.gv")`** will then save the dependency graph in the [Graphviz/DOT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)), which can then be rendered out to an image using local or browser-based software:

[image]